How do I check if the name of an NSG in Azure matches "nsg-....."?
I am creating a policy in Azure to check if all subnets have NSG, if it is a subnet and it does not have NSG or the NSG associated with the subnet does not start with "nsg-" the policy should be non-compliant, the "Audit" effect will be applied ", doing it this way, for example, doesn't work:
not: {
        field: 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/networkSecurityGroup.name'
        like: 'nsg-*'
     }   


Ensure that the policy checks if a subnet has an associated NSG. Use like to match the NSG name pattern (nsg-*). Apply not condition to mark subnets without an NSG or with a mismatched NSG name as non-compliant.

Actually, you can also use contains

To create an Azure Policy to check if the name of a NSG associated with a subnet starts with "nsg-", and ensure that the policy is non-compliant if no NSG is associated or the NSG name does not match the pattern, you can use the policy definition:
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/networkSecurityGroup",
              "exists": "false"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/networkSecurityGroup.name",
                "contains": "nsg-"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}

This policy will audit all subnets and mark those without an NSG or with an NSG name that doesn’t start with "nsg-" as non-compliant.
Example-
Subnet 1 without NSG would be marked as non-compliant.
Subnet 2 with NSG named "custom-nsg" would also be show as non-compliant because its NSG name doesn't start with "nsg-".
Subnet 3 with NSG named "nsg-arko" would be considered compliant.
Assign the policy

after you assign the policy, it will audit the subnets which are having NSG where NSG name that doesn’t start with "nsg-" as non-compliant.

Reference-
MS doc for handling NSG
Azure Policy Definition rules
